# Why "the line segment in $\mathbb{C}$ joining $f$ and $g$ does not pass through $0$"

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Every single algebraic topology problem I've encountered is leaving me baffled. I just can't visualise what is going on and why.

> Q. $f,g:X \to S^1$ such that $f(x) \neq -g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Construct a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.

is the question. Here's the answer

> The line segment in $\mathbb{C}$ joining $f$ to $g$ does not pass through $0$.(uh, why? does it matter? Is there a problem if it does? what restricts it to NOT pass $0$? I am so lost) The map
>
> $$h(x,t)=\frac{(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)}{||(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)||}$$
>
> is well-defined since $(1-t)f(x)+tg(x) \neq \in \mathbb{C}$ and defines a homotopy.

So again, I don't get what it's trying to say when it says "The line segment joining $\mathbb{C}$ joining $f$ to $g$ does not pass through $0$" I mean, what does this matter?

And also, my answer to this question was $h(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$. Just simply that. Not something like $h(x,t)=\frac{(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)}{||(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)||}$(I mean, yeah I guess this works as a homotopy as well, but is there a problem to keep it to $h(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$?Simpler?)

And finally, what did the condition $f(x) \neq -g(x)$ have to do in solving this question? I don't see it come into play anywhere(well, I'm sure it did but not anywhere obvious)

As usual, not enjoying algebraic topology but I'm at least trying my best not to hate it, so any help is well appreciated, thanks

Comment: For well-definedness you need that $(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)\neq 0$ so you don't divide by zero. The path $t\mapsto (1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$ parametrises the straight line from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ and saying that it doesn't pass through zero means that $(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)\neq0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: And for the other question: The reason you divide by $\|(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)\|$ in the first place is so your homotopy actually lands in $S^1$. That need not be the case if you don't normalize.

Comment: If $f(x)\neq-g(x)$, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are points on the unit circle, not diametrically opposite.  So from high-school geometry, if $\theta=\angle fOg$ the straight line between them passes a distance $\sin(\theta/2)$ from the origin.

Comment: $f(x)\ne-g(x)$ means $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not opposite each other on the circle. So, the line connecting them doesn't pass through the circle's origin.